# Debug list comprehension inside for loop in Pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, pycharm, list-comprehension

I'm trying to debug a code snippet includes list comprehension inside loop.

```
list_a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list_b = ['a', 'b']
for x in list_a:
    print([i for i in list_b if i == x])
```

The code run okay when I run the entire script. However when I located a breakpoint before the *for* loop and try to run the *for* loop interactively I got the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/root/pycharm/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_exec2.py", line 3, in Exec
>       exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)
>     File "", line 2, in 
>     File "", line 2, in 
>   NameError: name 'x' is not defined

I'm using pycharm for debugging.

Comment: what ide are you using ? I've been using Pycharm and didn't get your error

Comment: Pycharm too, I get the error only when I directly run the for loop (i.e copy paste it in debug mode to the console prompt)

Comment: I think it's similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17290314/possible-bug-in-pdb-module-in-python-3-when-using-list-generators or https://github.com/inducer/pudb/issues/103

Answer (score 0):

best way to debug a list comprehension is to use a simple for loop :

from:

`[i for i in list_b if i == x]`

use:

```
for x in list_a:
    costum_list = []
    for i in list_b:
        if i == x:
            costum_list.append(i)
    print(costum_list)
```

but I just run your code and seems to be all fine

Comment: I agree it's simpler to debug for loops. However for the sake writing clean and readable code I prefer using list comprehension and want to directly debug them.

Comment: you wan to solve the problem or just to find a way to debug keeping the list comprehension? And by the way, generally speaking, using list comprehension instead of for loops is less readable  (specially when you have more than one for in the comprehension)

Comment: I want to solve the problem. Personally I prefer list comprehension over a for loops

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error few days back and what I did was just click `Remove All Watches` from debug console thanks to this [PyCharm referencing older, removed variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37753016/6194097) question. Right click on your `Variables` section and click `Remove All Watches` and re-run your debug process.

[image]

Comment: It's not that issue, I think it has to do with the debug process. I think it's similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17290314/possible-bug-in-pdb-module-in-python-3-when-using-list-generators or https://github.com/inducer/pudb/issues/103